# how to close a backgroundworker from a button click event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have written a C# program to call a function through backgndWorkerEnroll_DoWork. It will start from a for shown event.

On the other side I have a button click event. When that event occurs I call a function and it it returns success, I want to close the backgroundworker.

How can I achieve this?

My code below.

```
private void PwdCheck_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    resPwdValid = PwdValid();
    if (resPwdValid == true)
    {
         //backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
         this.Close();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{               
    tstVerify:
        resVerify = testVerfy();
        if (resVerify == true)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Matched");
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Not Matched");
           goto tstVerify;
        }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (resVerify == true)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

How can I close the backgroundrunner after my btnenter_click respwdvalid returns true?

Comment: Check the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx it illustrates exact what you needed

Comment: @Siva - please make an effort to format your questions properly!!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [Cancellation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You would call `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` I believe (you seem to have commented it out) and then in your `DoWork` code you should keep checking `BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` and exit your background thread early.